# selecting two column for autocomplete in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, autocomplete

i created a code for autocomplete in textbox 
my code is

```
 Try
        Dim adapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        con = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        con.Open()
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        sqlstr = "select customerid,cname from customer "
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        adapter.SelectCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlstr, con)
        adapter.Fill(dt)
        Dim r As DataRow
        txtcname.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Clear()
        For Each r In dt.Rows
            txtcname.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(r.Item(1).ToString)
        Next
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("error found")
    End Try
```

now i want through autocomplete i can select the selected column of id so that i can use that id in my next code to fetch the information of the customer

currently i am using this

```
Dim adapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        con = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        con.Open()
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        sqlstr = "select address1,mobileno from customer where cname='" & txtcname.Text & "' "
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        adapter.SelectCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlstr, con)
        adapter.Fill(dt)
        lbladdr.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(0)
        lblmono.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(1).ToString
        con.Close()
```

working fine but i have a primary key id in the customer table so how can i search information through the id of a customer ,